# How to work effectively with an unpredictable advisor?

Tags: graduate-school, advisor

I'm not sure if many grad students face these struggles, as my advisor is in no way abusive or "bad". In fact, she is extremely nice, but just very unpredictable at times. For instance, the same request or question will elicit a very different response depending on the day, and that's really confusing to navigate. I think predictability is kind of key to any type of managerial work.

In addition, she will also play her cards to get what she want. For instance, the advisor I thought I will have through her actions/words during the rotation period, is different from the advisor I ended up getting (little time to talk about my project now, and doesn't seem to care). This happened again when she was trying to have me stay on longer for a project. I wrote a research proposal, but once she realized I was staying, there was attitude change again. Meetings were post-phoned to the point that we never actually discussed any part of the proposal after two months. Now I'm having second thoughts about the whole thing, but would it seem immature to back out of it now? In general, I can't figure out if this is acceptable behaviour, and if I'm just not learning the best way of handling it.

Comment: You might want to give more examples of the behavior in question. So far, you state that your advisor is unpredictable, but provide little to no facts.

Comment: Are you productive? Is she good? Do her students have a good publication/academic record? Then you may overlook her disorganizedness (or manipulatively, depending). If not, you may want to switch.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I have been very productive so far... at producing negative results. Hence the need for mentorship, which is non-existent at times from her end. She is a good scientist, but probably not the greatest manager, although that's not rare in academia. None of her students have publications, since she's a newer professor.

Comment: Well, you answered your question yourself: she is a new professor, new to the job. Sometimes it may help to give her a indication what you would need from her, very diplomatic, very polite, but clear. If she does not follow up on that, consider switching supervisors. It is fine to back out from a supervisor that doesn't do their job well and do not promise to improve. It is your right to know what you expect from a supervision.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs - I think the comments you wrote should go in an answer.  Good response.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to glance around to see if there are other options.  That is a very important aspect to the decision, after all.

Comment: @aparente001 Made the comment a response, as per your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Your first and second paragraph don't really tell the same story. In the first paragraph, you mention that the same request will lead to two different answers "depending on the time of the day". In the second paragraph, the problem has little to do with predictability, and just seems to be that your advisor does not have as much time for you and interest in your work as you hoped (which is a very common complaint, as a short browse here in the archives will tell you).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I've attempted that but haven't had much success unfortunately. Every conversation basically starts and ends with the words "I'm really busy with..." When she wants to though, she helps with really small things for other people's projects right after telling me this, that it's almost like a slap in the face sometimes. Meetings are cancelled etc. In a public setting though, like when other PIs are around, she's a super helpful mentor figure, giving me advice on all things. To the extent that if I told other people I'm not getting enough help, they'll probably think I'm crazy..

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I'm really trying to make this not get to me, but it's really becoming difficult. Having a manager who "shows up" when she feels like it, getting absolutely no support, but still being micromanaged on small tasks just doesn't seem right. There are so few supervisors in my program I could switch to though, and they are all collaborators. I'll burn bridges for sure. She gives off such a nice vibe to any "outsiders" that people will probably just wonder what is wrong with me for not making it work.

Comment: @Cornyvita That doesn't sound good. Either she is very disorganised and only external "peer pressure" makes her behave like a superviser has to, or she is a - excuse the word - manipulative personality. The micromanagement part may point to the first and she tries to cover that up in public. However, it could be the second, in which case, do you have the chance to switch to some other department/uni?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Yes, I think it's the first as well mostly, although that doesn't make it easier to cope with. There are definitely other universities I can switch to, but I don't think I'm up for that level of change at this point in grad school, and consider my last year lost. I do have job offers though, and am seriously considering just dropping out and getting away from this.

Comment: @Cornyvita And dropping a PhD is less of a loss than one year? This is the calculation you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

She is a new professor, new to the job. Sometimes it may help to give her a indication what you would need from her, very diplomatic, very polite, but clear. If she does not follow up on that, consider switching supervisors. It is fine to back out from a supervisor that doesn't do their job well and do not promise to improve. It is your right to know what to expect from a supervision.

Comment: @Cornyvita - Yes, do provide clear feedback and guidance, i.e. assert yourself gently; but also take a look around you to see what other advisor prospects there are.  You wouldn't want to go from the frying pan into the fire.